# Fastest way to get a file from a URL

Tags: c#, .net

From the performance point of view, what is the fastest way to get a file from web.

Webclient, httpwebrequest etc?

Comment: Just how many requests are you planning on making?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WebClient` uses `HttpWebRequest` under the covers (see [`WebClient.GetWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.getwebrequest.aspx)), so it's not an either/or.  Just use `WebClient` if the abstraction works for your application.

Answer (score 6):

The vast *vast* ***vast*** majority of your time here will be spent actually waiting for data from the remote server to reach you. This may still be on the order of milliseconds for small files, or may be hours for that multi-gigabyte database (or whatever) your app needs. The API you use to retrieve that file is not even going to register as a blip on the performance radar in comparison to TCP/IP.

So in short: from "the performance point of view," they're all exactly the same. Write your code to use one approach or another, and if you find that your code actually is slower than it ought to be, then come back and let us know and we'll be able to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

WebClient internally creates an instance of WebRequest, so they're pretty much the same.